# How to know the functions we can use with a go package?

Tags: go

I am learning the go language and write my first go program, with the help of some web sources:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {

    ba := []byte("HelloWorld")
    hasher := sha512.New()
    hasher.Write(ba)
    sha := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))

    fmt.Printf(sha)

}
```

It compiles and works as expected, but I couldn't write this code myself since if i look at the Go package reference for [sha256](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256), I don't see the `Write()` and the `Sum()` methods. Where to find this kind of information? Maybe, I'm not reading the good document, or there is a sort of "inheritance" I didn't see.

Comment: There's a tool for this called [Oracle](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle). IDE's also use it for code-completion.

Comment: Saved for later (when i will understand better go lang)

Comment: Depending on which editor you use, visual studio code, sublime text, atom and vim all have excellent code completion plugins for Go. I personally use https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash implementations are all provided through a common [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) [interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types).

If you look at the docs for [`sha512.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha512/#New), you'll see that it returns a [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash), which lists all the `Hash` specific methods.

The first field in the `hash.Hash` interface is an [embedded](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), which is what provides the standard `Write` method.

All these values are links in the documentation, which you can follow the to the required definitions, and even to the source.

Comment: I forgot to check the source, it helps

Answer (score 0):

The `Sum()` and `Write()` functions are part of the [`Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) interface, which is implemented by all different kind of hashs.

Answer (score 0):

`hash.Hash` returns a `Hash` interface, which include `io.Writer`. If you check the `io.Writer`, you will find a `Writer` interface, which has a `Write()` method. Because the `sha512` package does implement the Write method, you can call the `Write` as a `hasher` method.

The only requirement to access an interface is to implemente the method defined in your custom scope.